# "Failed to deserialize" when using dask.dataframe.from_delayed on a collection of pandas DataFrames

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, dask, lazy-evaluation

**Describe the issue**:
I'm currently trying to read from a database in parallel using Dask and Pandas. I'm creating a collection of Dask delayed objects using pd.read_sql and then using Dask's from_delayed method to produce a Dask DataFrame. Unfortunately I'm working with a secure database so I can't provide a copy/paste-able example, but the following code comes pretty close:

**Minimal Complete Verifiable Example**:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.delayed import delayed
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

def load_table_in_parallel(metadata, table_name, index_column):

    # Construct database connection URI and create engine
    connection_uri = "sybaseiq://username:password@XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/XXX"
   engine = create_engine(connection_uri)

    # Create column metadata
    dd.utils.make_meta(pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM {table_name}", 
                                         connection_uri))

    # Create Table object that reflects requested database table
    table = Table(table_name, metadata, autoload_with_engine, quote=False)
    
    return dd.read_sql_query(select(table),
                             connection_uri,
                             index_column,
                             npartitions=16,
                             meta=meta,
                             head_rows=0)

# This line is where the error occurs
load_table_in_parallel().compute()
```

The code breaks if I try to SELECT more than 1 field in any of the SQL queries listed. In particular, I get a long error message (which I can't export due to privacy restrictions) which begins with "Failed to deserialize" and ends with "CanceledError: ('from-delayed-c9f959ldkjfd8032a', 1)"

**Environment**:

- Dask version: 2023.6.0
- Python version: 3.11.3
- Operating System: RedHat Linux
- Install method (conda, pip, source): Conda

Comment: Hard to tell without the full stack trace and just a code sample. Do you get the Pandas only part working without usinng Dask? On which call does the error occur?

Comment: Yes, the pandas part works without Dask. Here is the stack trace: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/d42vc6hof69nfb0iyz3o4/h?rlkey=golfl1ownwkvqxouju5elbq03&dl=0

Comment: Sorry, but it's really hard to look at it as a picture.